# Crystal report Group 1 trigger Group 2

Tags: triggers, crystal-reports, group, disable

I have a crystal report with 2 groups. Everytime the group 1 data change it trigger the group 2.

I'm looking to find a way to prevent the trigger of group 2 when group 1 data change. Prevent it or hide group 2 and show on a condition formula based on data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since level-2 grouping is embedded inside the level-1 grouping, crossing the boundary of a level-1 group must also cross the boundary of a level-2 group.

One option is to define your grouping logic differently.
Another option is to use the Previous() function or a global variable to track the previous level-2 value and compare it to the current level-2 value.

It would be easier to provide a more specific answer if you provide a concrete example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you provide an exemple on how to use a global variable? I'm really novice in CR